# Bind data from one layout file to another

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding

I'm trying to use android's data binding library but I'm getting this error:

> Error:(29, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@{string/table}').
>
> Error:(30, 27) No resource
>   found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value
>   '@{drawable/ic_table}').

My question is: Can I bind data from one layout file to another?  And what is wrong with my code?

**activity.xml:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ....
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include layout="@layout/image_with_text"
            android:id="@+id/tag_table"
            app:title="@{string/table}"
            app:icon="@{drawable/ic_table}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
.....
```

**image_with_text.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />
        <variable
            name="title"
            type="java.lang.String" />
        <variable
            name="icon"
            type="Drawable" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@{icon}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@{title}"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I tryied changing to  app:title="@{@string/table}" but when I run the code, Android Studio changes to app:title="@{string/table}". Idk if that makes any difference.

Also, I do have this string in my string file

```
 <string name="table">Table</string>
```

Comment: whats wrong with `app:title="@string/table"`?

Comment: @pskink it auto-correct back to   app:title="@{string/table}"